# Can i add trednlines to line charts using image-charts

Tags: image-charts

I really enjoy this image-charts.com service. Is there a way to add trendlines a line chart? I have attempted to add this parameter

`trendlines: { 0: {} }` from google (as that is their trendline code and this is powered by google?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might like to have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add trendlines a line chart?

Yes, that's what we call a [compound chart](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/compound-charts/), follow the 3 steps and you are good to go (note: it will require a Enterprise+ subscription).

[image]

[image]

You can also use [editor.image-charts.com](https://editor.image-charts.com/?tab_viewer=image#https:/image-charts.com/chart?chbh=5,2&chco=224499,009900&chd=s2:1XQbnf4,EWoQMUB,9halxp9&chm=D,0033FF,2,0,5,1&chs=700x200&cht=bvs&chxl=0:%7CJan%7CFeb%7CMar%7CApr%7CMay%7CJun%7CJul&chxt=x,y&icac=fgribreau&icretina=1&ichm=50b2279db66f1398e4ee22ec9ce3f75c2f12355307dc71e9e444cb678fb7bab7) editor to easily edit your static chart (again, if you wish to leverage compound charts you will have to take an Enterprise+ subscription).